# Hiding/Showing columns from the Datatables plugin th?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a table similar to this:

```
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to be able to do is put some sort of image or link to hide and show columns in the `<th>`.  When the user clicks to hide a column, I want to put the inner text of the `<th>` in a div and when the div is clicked on, I want the user to be able to click on the column of their choice and put it back in the table and remove it from the div.

I got the datatables plugin to work and on the website, it has a sample of hiding/showing columns, but with external links.  I was able to add a link to hide/show a column, but here are my problems:

I don't know how to get the index or column that was clicked.
I don't know how to remove it from the div using jquery.  When I click show/hide, it puts it in the div, but then it keeps repeating for every click and I can also click it in the div and it shows/hides in the table depending on its current state.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datatable').dataTable();

            $('.showhide').live('click', function() {

                var index = $('#datatable th').index();

                fnShowHide(index);
            });
        });

        function fnShowHide(iCol) {
            var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable();

            var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;

            oTable.fnSetColumnVis(iCol, bVis ? false : true);

            var index = $('#datatable td').index();
            console.log(index);

            $('#columns').append('<a href="#">' + oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[index].sTitle + '<a/>');

        }
    </script>

<div id="columns"><h4>Columns</h4></div>
    <table id="datatable" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I left out some of the table data.

Comment: Have you tried... anything?

Comment: It would be beneficial if you posted code of what you've tried.  It's easier to debug.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - Posted some code, but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a datatable that expands collapses rows, and how i handled knowing which row was clicked was to

1) Assign an element id to each TR row, aaData contains my data, the node at the number one position of aaData is my unique identifier (if its the first node it would be aaData[0])

```
$( '#records' ).dataTable({
               "bJQueryUI": true, 
               "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) { 
                                                $(nRow).attr('id', aaData[1]);
                                                return nRow; 
                                                            } ,
               "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }],
               "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
 });
```

now your subsequent events can reference the TR id

```
$('#records tbody td img').on('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
    {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        this.src = "../ci/images/details_open.png";
        dataTable.fnClose( nTr );
    } ... });
```

*note that if its numeric you may want to append some text prior , numeric only element id's can create javascript/jquery problems and i think not html compliant